# Can I make iCloud Preferences forget an old AppleID (mac OS SIerra)?

Tags: icloud, macos, apple-id

I successfully logged out of iCloud on mac OS Sierra, but now every time I go to iCloud in Preferences, it shows the old AppleID. Is there any way to get iCloud to completely forget the AppleID and behave as if I had never logged in before?

Comment: To be clear: all you want is your old Apple ID not being pre-filled in System Preferences > iCloud, from which you've signed out?

Comment: Yes, @Redarm, that is exactly what I am looking for, and your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check shows that quitting System Preferences and deleting the folder...
`~/Library/Accounts/`
...followed by subsequent log out and log in, gets rid of the pre-filled Apple ID.
After that a new sign-in request from iMessage/FaceTime appears.

Other than that there seems to be an abundance of account types listed in the database within the "Accounts" folder, so logging into those might be required again.
To see a list of account types held in the database, run this command in Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities, or via Spotlight):

```
echo 'SELECT ZACCOUNTTYPEDESCRIPTION FROM ZACCOUNTTYPE;' | sqlite3 ~/Library/Accounts/Accounts4.sqlite
```

...and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This has not been tested for any long term side effects.

Comment: Deleting the `~/Library/Accounts/` folder did the trick. This was for a utility-drive where I did not want any personal accounts linked, so this worked fine for me.
I confess I did not try the shell (Terminal) code, so I don't know if it would have worked, or what else was in there. Thank You!

Comment: After logging back in, that folder is re-generated, which is not surprising and is presumably a "factory fresh" (i.e., empty) version of the sqlite database. The code you provided returns a fairly long list of account types even in this default library, so it does at least give an indication of what accounts you will have to log into again if you delete the `Accounts` folder.  Thanks again.